# How to set background color for specific section header?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, header

I have a `TableView` with 10 sections that are loaded from a plist file and I have switches with which some of the sections can be turned off. I need to set a specific background color for each section with the fact that the section can be disabled.

Example:

for section `Black` I need to set `black background`

for section `Red` I need to set `red background`

and so on...

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *tempHeaderView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,44)];
     tempHeaderView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];

     [tempHeaderView addSubView: tempHeaderLabel];
     return tempHeaderView;
}
```

Comment: Unless you are using ARC (Automatic reference counting), your code is leaking tempHeaderView. Check out my answer for a fix in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep an `NSArray` of `UIColor` objects as an instance variable of your class (the view controller that acts as delegate/data source), say you call it `sectionColors`. You can initialize the colors in this array from values in your plist, or hard-code the colors.

Then, use this code:

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *tempHeaderView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,44)];


    // This changed:
    tempHeaderView.backgroundColor = [sectionColors objectAtIndex:section];

    [tempHeaderView addSubView: tempHeaderLabel];

    return tempHeaderView;
    // Use 'return [tempHeaderView autorelease];' in a non-ARC environment
}
```

This is how you could initialize the array:

```
// Assuming your table has three sections (indices 0 through 2)

UIColor* colorForSection0 = [UIColor colorwithRed:redValue0 green:greenValue0 blue:blueValue0 alpha:1.0];
// redValue0, etc. are floats between 0.0 and 1.0 that you can read from a .plist
// Alternatively, store them as integers between 0 and 255, and divide them by 255.0 
// and store on CGFloat variables before creating color.

// ...Do the same for the other colors...

// Now that you have the colors, create array and store in ivar 'sectionColors'
sectionColors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: 
    ColorforSection0, ColorForSection1, colorForSection2, nil];
```

(the code above should go inside the table view data source's initializer)

Comment: UIColor is not directly storable in a plist, but this concept could easily be adapted to use strings in the plist to represent which color to use.

Comment: Of course... But you can read the R,G,B values from the plist and initialize the colors accordingly. But the idea is the same: he needs an array of UIColor and to select the color at index 'section'. I didn't go into detail of HOW he is supposed to create the array.

Comment: I just edited the answer to make it clear that you can't read UIColor from .plist directly.

Comment: I'll give you an example and you will give me a tick ;)

Comment: Note on MVC purity; it is recommended that anything in the plist be model only (i.e. a sections 'enabled' state), and not style (i.e. what color a disabled section should be). So a solution like this should involve the view being responsible for contraction the array of UIColors. Pedantic, perhaps, but we have these patterns for a reason so it's worth mentioning.

Comment: I'm not an InterfaceBuilder expert, but perhaps there's a way to store an array of colors somewhere in the relevant NIB?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use the passed-in section and relate it to one of the sections in your plist file. You will probably load a dictionary of the "section" as it exists in the plist (probably loaded based on it's position in an array being the same as section), and then use valueForKey:@"enabled" or similar in an if() check, and set your state accordingly.